# Has there been any attempt at literary analysis on the addictive and engaging qualities of JK Rowling's writing?

Tags: harry-potter, literary-analysis

I have just started re-reading the Harry Potter series by way of reading it to my youngest child. In doing so, I've been reminded of how fascinated I was by how Rowling's writing pulls the reader in and holds them there. On the surface, it does not appear especially well written or cleverly constructed by the standard of other published and bestselling authors. Yet, clearly, it speaks powerfully to a vast number of readers, myself included.

Trying to elucidate why is beyond the scope of a Q & A site like this. However, I hope that asking whether or not any academics have tried to analyse the literary qualities success of the series might not be.

I am particularly interested in understanding how the writing is structured to maximise engagement with the reader. Take Harry's encounter with Ollivander, for example. The writing is simple, the sentences short. There is little description or dialogue. Yet Ollivander nevertheless emerges well sketched as a mysterious, vaguely sinister character and the lore of wands appears instantly fascinating.

That's just an example to illustrate what I'm seeking to learn more about: I have no especial interest in that passage alone. Can anyone point me at some academic discourse, ideally peer-reviewed, around this subject?

Comment: https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=%22harry+potter%22+rowling&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5

Comment: http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/kitchener-waterloo/harry-potter-class-debuts-at-university-of-waterloo-1.3559205

Comment: VTC - It's a good question, but the only clear answers are Yes or No, anything else devolves into discussion or recommendation.   You might check out - http://www.hogwartsprofessor.com/.

Comment: @TGnat Fair point. Thanks for the link. Is it worth editing to ask people to list well-received papers/essays on the subject?

Comment: You can also try asking this on Writers SE - they probably know stuff

Comment: @TGnat A good, complete answer to this question would be an affirmative with links to examples of literary scholarship.  Really, your mini-answer in the comment could be an adequate answer.  It's just a simple question.  ;)

Comment: @SudoSedWinifred If that is an acceptable answer, and the community agrees, then I would support a request to reopen.

Comment: @TGnat I have attempted to edit the question to make it more specific and started a reopen vote. I can understand why this may be a poor fit: we'll see if this is any better.

Comment: i'd say given the ultimate nature of the question - it belongs in writing.se

Comment: @MattThrower - Well, you've taken it from "**off-topic: too broad**" to "**off-topic: recommendations**". I'm not sure that's much of an improvement.